# Upgraded XCode to 6.3.1, now app will not run on device

Tags: xcode6.3, ios8.3

I just upgraded to XCode 6.3.1 and my app runs fine on all of the 8.x simulators, but not on my device, which was also upgraded to iOS 8.3.  The app *won't even load on the device* (iPad 2).

I need to test my camera code (which also stopped working for the app's users). Any ideas on how to fix this?  (already did a project->clean, stopped and restarted XCode and the device).

Comment: Any errors in the output?

Comment: There is no output... the app doesn't even show up on the device!  Never seen anything like this before...  SD

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong Provisioning Profile i.e. Distribution for development. It's working now... thanks...